# "Esente" + "di" o "da"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Quale preposizione si deve usare dopo l'aggettivo "esente"? "Di" oppure "da"? Cercando su Google ho trovato esempi di uso sia di "esente di" che di "esente da",  cosa che mi ha fatto pensare che forse siano ambedue corrette.

Comment: Potresti presentare gli esempi di "esente di"?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi:    Ecco un esempio su Amazon, http://www.amazon.it/gp/aw/d/B00LFQA4SG/279-3580159-5269334#productDescription_secondary_view_pageState_1423139224913,  e un altro su Google books, https://books.google.es/books?id=rxdjBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA384&dq=%22esenti+di%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tWLTVOQniaxT-LGE8Ak&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22esenti%20di%22&f=false

Comment: Anche questo: https://books.google.es/books?id=wlzHcEaNy7gC&pg=PA168&dq=%22esenti+di%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=82XTVJFHy6tT4pqDkAE&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAzge#v=onepage&q=%22esenti%20di%22&f=false

Comment: Non riesco ad accedere all esempio di Google books.  L'altro mi sembra decisamente un errore grammaticale

Comment: il primo esempio non è decisamente in italiano corretto, puzza di Google translator. Il secondo esempio parla di "operazioni esenti" (da tasse) di oro. Cioè operazioni di oro esenti da tasse.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi: Capisco. Grazie! Penso che l'altro esempio di Google Books sia simile a questo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non ho mai trovato esempi di "esente di".

Si usa "esente da", ad esempio:

- Esente dal servizio militare
- Esente dal pagare le tasse
- Esente dal mettere la divisa

e così via